# Way to decline pull request programmatically in BitBucket repo when build failed in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, bitbucket-cloud

I have a build pipeline on azure devops that is configured to run whenever a pull request is made to a BitBucket repository.
I'm looking for a configuration so that the pull request in Bitbucket is automatically denied if the build pipeline I created in azure devops fails, but so far I've only figured out how to do this for azure repo:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops

Is there any way to configure branch policies in Azure Devops for BitBucket repo?